# Inspect contents of a basic, unencrypted UDIF DMG file

Tags: macos, file-format, dmg

If I mount the DMG file using system calls to `hdiutil` and my application quits unexpectedly, the DMG remains mounted but because I mount it privately with `-nobrowse`, it doesn't show up in Finder. Is there a way to mount it using some framework or API that will be smart enough to unmount if my application unexpectedly quits?

Basically, I'm looking for a way to be able to read from files within a DMG without having to mount it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [libdmg](http://github.com/planetbeing/libdmg-hfsplus/tree/master) to directly read the dmg rather than mounting it....though it's obviously unsupported.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to try to catch an exception or signal prior to exiting, and in your exception or signal handler code, unmount the DMG yourself.